# How to keep on showing the close icon when hover on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a `div` with id `area` on my page.

I want to show a close icon at right corner(it is inside the div) when user's mouse enter on this `DIV`. Everything is working fine but the issue is when user hover on close icon `#closeicon` area , it will hide the icon.

So please suggest how can i keep on showing the close icon when user hover on it.

Here is my code:

```
$("#area").on('mouseenter',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            showCloseIcon();

    }).on('mouseleave',function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
        var except=$("#closeicon");
        if(!except.is(e.target) && except.has(e.target).length===0){
            hideCloseIcon();     
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

closeicon is not the child of the area DIV. I am positioning it over area div using css(absolute position) due to some reason.

Comment: If it is inside the div, why dont you use css only?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon i just made a EDIT on my question "closeicon is not the child of the area DIV. I am positioning it over area div using css(absolute position)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
$('#area, #closeicon').hover(function(){
    $('#closeicon').show();
}, function(){
    $('#closeicon').hide()
})
```

Just bind your event on both id's.

Also, I used `.hover` since it shorter and do the same thing as `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`. in the same call.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/S9LQY/

Answer (score 0):

$("#area") >> $("#area, #closeicon")

Comment: closeicon is not the child of the area DIV. I am positioning it over area div using css(absolute position).

Comment: that's what the comma's for

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is something you're looking for, but you can just use CSS for this:

```
#closeicon {
    display: none;
}

#area:hover > #closeicon {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: closeicon is not the child of the area DIV. I am positioning it over area div using css(absolute position).